# Web API Per client request limitation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I start to get crazy with something I do not understand.
I created a Web API project with dotnet cli :

`dotnet new webapi`

In the Get method of the controller, I copied the following code :

```js
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Start");

    await Task.Delay(10000);
    
    _logger.LogInformation("End");

    return Ok();
}
```

I run the service and I open 4 tabs on the swagger endpoint, 2 from Chrome and 2 from Edge.

When I execute the code from different browsers, it is OK, the two calls are executed in parallel. If I launch the code twice from the same browser, the execution is not in parallel.

So it looks like there is some kind of **per-client limitation** but I not able to disable it.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o697.gif), it seems that your code works well on my side (create a new asp.net core API application), not matter in the save browsers or different browsers, the calls are executed in parallel.

Comment: Indeed, with different input parameter, it works as expected but what about without parameter or with the same parameter value ?

Comment: Hi @Gnet, Yes, with the same parameter value, when using the same browsers, the execution is not in parallel. But if I send the request programmatically or using PostMan, even with the same parameter value, the execution will be in parallel. So, the issue might relate the Swagger, but I didn't find any document about this, you could try to post this question on the Swagger Forum or contact with them.